# Observable doesn't recognise map operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

**update**

I noticed a weird behaviour! i have few methods in this service and i get different responses (one mapped properly and the other looks strange). i updated the code.

**someService.ts:**

```
        import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
        import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
        import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

        @Injectable()
        export class someService {

          constructor(private _http:Http) {  }

            getSession():Observable<IUser> { // i get a response like that [object object]
          this.getsession = this._http.get("/url");
          return this.getsession.map((response) => <IUser> response.json());
          }

        getUser():Observable<IUser> { // i get the the response object mapped here as one of the comments said the response doesn't have data object
          this.user = this._http.get("/url");
          return this.user.map(response => <User> response.json());
      }
        }
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {IUser} from "../common/user";
import {SomeService} from "../services/someService.service";

@Component({
  selector: "user",
  templateUrl: "./user.component.html",
})
export class User implements OnInit {
  user:IUser;

  constructor( private _someService:SomeService) {
  }

  getUser() {
    this._someService.getSession().subscribe((data) => {
      this.user = data; // the response looks like this: [object Object]
    }, (err) => {
      this.errorMsg = ""
    });
  }
  ngOnInit():void {
  }
}
```

**The JSON object i'm getting from rest:**

```
{"uid":"***","name":"Test","mail":null,"gname":null,"sn":null,"isEn":true,"user":"**"}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: @Hazu do you get any error while you are using map?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i get undefined if i use the map operator! without mapping i get the observable object

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya No i get no error in my console

Comment: what I'm guessing is that your response does **not** have `data` object...

Comment: @AJT_82 It doesn't seem to be the problem! I tried removing it still the same!

Comment: okay, how **does** your response look like? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 sorry for late response! I updated my code since i noticed strange behaviour!

Comment: @AJT_82 i was experimenting! but it's the same! for getSession() the response after subscription looks like this   [object Object] ! am getting json object as a response from the rest service which looks right when debugging!

Comment: Please show the JSON response (in JSON format) and the component code in your question.

Comment: @AJT_82 the code is updated! thanks

Comment: it should work just fine, and as I said I would make the request differently like in previous comment :) http://plnkr.co/edit/5El0NqESIvpt71GWqpb4?p=preview

Comment: i still get [object object] :( !! i actually wrote the request like this to log the variable before the return. It definitely looks ugly!

Comment: I don't really know how else to help. As seen in plunker it *should* work correctly. Hmm...

Comment: Thanks anyway for your help! appreciate it :)

Comment: Any changes using `=> (response.json() as IUser)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this import at the top

If you want all operators

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

If you want just the map operator

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

If neither works try restarting your IDE

Comment: If you import `rxjs/Rx`, you get **everything**, so the second import is redundant.

Comment: sorry I should have added an or I will update my answer

Comment: The 2nd line is exactly the same as shown in the question, so this is rather unlikely to be the solution.